# Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174, Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless, atheros, xps

I am experiencing internet connection issues for a few days. After logging in the internet connection works for a few minutes and then breaks down.

Kernel Version using `uname -a`

```
Linux xps 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried using `kernel 4.15.0-54-generic` having the same issues.

Consulting `journalctl --follow` I can see frequent messages (also for TCP)

```
systemd-resolved[538]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server
```

---

**Update 1**
Redirecting the symlink `/etc/resolv.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` removed the occurance of `Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server` from the `journalctl --follow` output. So I guess this is not the cause of my problems

---

On restarting my network manager via `sudo service network-manager restart` the connection comes back to break down a again a few minutes later.

Additional info

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:fc:21:8f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-55-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.0.192 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:139 memory:ed200000-ed3fffff

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Device 1c5c:1527
```

Comment: Is it any better if you `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf && systemctl restart network-manager.service`

Comment: I am afraid turning off power saving mode for the wifi card (which is I guess what your suggesting) does not help

Comment: I have had a few Atheros wifi cards in Linux, they don't like power management or TKIP encryption

Comment: I have a similar problem with a full ubuntu. See here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362145/using-degraded-feature-set-tcp-instead-of-udp-for-dns-server-wifi-connection