# Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server [WiFi connection]

Tags: ssh, internet, acer, 21.04, disconnect

My laptop disconnects every 5 minutes but it is always connected to the wifi, which correctly works (I can see that it works from other devices).
I have tried with another browser but it is the same, in addition I have experienced the same loss of connection with a ssh file transfer.

Using the command `sudo journalctl --since="-2 minutes"` , just **after** the connection crash, I get:

```
set 10 11:11:22 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 10.64.10.16.
set 10 11:11:27 acer-Aspire-A315-56 pkexec[4942]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
set 10 11:11:27 acer-Aspire-A315-56 pkexec[4942]: acer: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/acer] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifie>
set 10 11:11:37 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 10.64.10.15.
set 10 11:11:38 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
set 10 11:11:42 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 10.64.10.16.
set 10 11:11:55 acer-Aspire-A315-56 gnome-shell[1076]: Window manager warning: Ping serial 456584 was reused for window 0xa00006, previous use was fo>
set 10 11:12:09 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 10.64.10.15.
set 10 11:12:29 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 10.64.10.16.
set 10 11:12:30 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 10.64.10.15.
set 10 11:12:35 acer-Aspire-A315-56 gnome-shell[5085]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
set 10 11:12:36 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 10.64.10.16.
set 10 11:12:41 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 10.64.10.15.
set 10 11:12:56 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 10.64.10.16.
set 10 11:13:01 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 10.64.10.15.
set 10 11:13:01 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd[920]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
set 10 11:13:02 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd[920]: Started VTE child process 5212 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 1806.
set 10 11:13:02 acer-Aspire-A315-56 gnome-shell[1076]: libinput error: event5  - USB Optical Mouse: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 25>
set 10 11:13:06 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 10.64.10.16.
set 10 11:13:06 acer-Aspire-A315-56 sudo[5227]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
set 10 11:13:07 acer-Aspire-A315-56 systemd-resolved[582]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 10.64.10.15.
set 10 11:13:09 acer-Aspire-A315-56 sudo[5227]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
set 10 11:13:09 acer-Aspire-A315-56 sudo[5227]:     acer : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/acer ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl --since=-2 minutes
set 10 11:13:09 acer-Aspire-A315-56 sudo[5227]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
```

Imho the most relevant line is "(...) **Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 10.64.10.16.**"

My ubuntu version is 21.04, and my laptop is an Acer Aspire 3 A315-56 with a WiFi connection.

Comment: This needs some clarity. Does the WiFi always work or does it disconnect every 5 mins?

Comment: @David the words "wifi correctly works" are imho quite clear. The wifi is ok, I can observe its behaviour from the download plot of other devices. Anyway I have done an edit.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator the history is clipped at two hours ago. If I can have a more recent history I can map what I get from the related history messages with the descriptions of `man journalctl `.

Comment: @waltinator I have done an edit. The history shows that the system has been connected but it doesn't tell why a disconnection occur.

Comment: Within 4 minutes of WiFi dropping, `sudo journalctl --since="-5 minutes"` will show everything that's logged. Is the other end doing it?

Comment: @waltinator via edit I have added the journal which starts from the launch of the browser (Opera) up to the connection crash. Of course many lines are useless for the characterization of the problem.

Comment: I had installed ubuntu version 20. This problem troubled me so much i just had to switch back to 18. I literally tried all solutions provided on the internet but non worked. My advice is go back to 18. Its way stable and drivers do not crash at all. Another thing you should note version 20 was crashing due to Nvidia drivers

Comment: @AndrewMititi I will pay attention to your advise. Consider that my laptop doesn't have to deal with Nvidia drivers because (unfortunately) I have an Intel GPU.

Comment: I have asked more or less the same [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1676584/using-degraded-feature-set-tcp-instead-of-udp-for-dns-server/1676778#1676778) on superuser.